# Determining Flanking letters of a substring in a single step using regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to cut up a list of letters using `cutters` where the corresponding position of the letter in `cutters` cuts at `cutspots` in such a way that 'K' (`cutspots` 1), cuts after a letter when read left-to-right, and 'S' (`cutspots` 0) cuts before a letter.

I currently need to use a list comprehension inside another list comprehension to confirm this, but I'd like to lower this to a single list comprehension while returning the location of the word that is found to be successfully cut by this pattern in `beginning` and `end`.

Is there a more clever way to go about doing this?

```
import re

letterlist = 'GIURELABGIRUGHAWUWORDHGUOIHRUANOTHERKHVUHREIAVHRELGBEIUVIREUVBKWORDSGOREGK'

cutters = ['K', 'S']
cutspots = [1, 0]

wordlist = 'WORD'

end = [[m.start() for m in re.finditer(wordlist, letterlist) if letterlist[m.start()+len(wordlist)-abs(0-cutspots[position])] is cutters[position]] for position in range(len(cutters))]

beginning = [[m.start() for m in re.finditer(wordlist, letterlist) if letterlist[m.start()-cutspots[position]] is cutters[position]] for position in range(len(cutters))]
```

Comment: please include a clear expected input and output

Comment: So this currently has the expected input and output, but I'd like to have the same output with less code if possible. The current output is the location of the first letter of the substring location where the cut is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/50muEG/1)

```
(?<=K)(?=WORDS)
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/dKfT8W)

```
import re

p = re.compile(r"(?<=K)(?=WORDS)")
s = "GIURELABGIRUGHAWUWORDHGUOIHRUANOTHERKHVUHREIAVHRELGBEIUVIREUVBKWORDSGOREGK"

for m in re.finditer(p,s):
    print m.span()
```

#### Usage 2

This version allows you to change the regex with variables.

```
import re

c = ["K", "S"]
w = "WORD"
p = re.compile(r"(?<=" + re.escape(c[0]) + r")(?=" + re.escape(w) + re.escape(c[1]) + r")")
s = "GIURELABGIRUGHAWUWORDHGUOIHRUANOTHERKHVUHREIAVHRELGBEIUVIREUVBKWORDSGOREGK"

for m in re.finditer(p,s):
    print m.span()
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=K)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is `K` literally
- `(?=WORDS)` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is `WORD` and `S` (`WORDS`) literally

Python has the method [`.span()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.span) that returns the position of the regex match.

Comment: So this is pretty close but I want it to find 'WORD' after a 'K' and before an 'S'. I wasn't aware of that tool, thanks for sharing. How might I put the "before S" part in there?

Comment: @NameyMcNamo this has `S` after the word. You would simply construct the regex by using `re.escape()` on the cutters input.

Comment: So for my actual code I would need it to be more flexible, I iterate through different letters that can cut either before or after depending on the letter. I'd have a harder time concatenating a letter at the end if it cut before a letter. I currently use the cutspots to differentiate between the two.